# Pandas - Skip over rows that "apply" function throws error on

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this simple code

```
import ast

df = df["strings"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Which just converts a column of a list in string form back into a string. I get an error `ValueError: malformed node or string: 0`, I'd like `apply` to just skip over the rows it fails and just return a Dataframe of the rows it was successful on. How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is a list "in string form"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by "in string form" you mean a list of a single string (like `["foo"]`).

You could accomplish what you're asking using a simple wrapper function applied over the dataframe:

```
import ast

def wrap(x):
    try:
        a = ast.literal_eval(x)
        return(a)
    except:
        pass

df = df["strings"].apply(wrap)
```

It may be better practice, however, to evaluate why the rows in your dataframe are causing an error in the first place. Garbage in, Garbage out.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap ast.literal_eval in a try/except block. Consider the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

def func(s):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(s)
    except:
        return []

data = list(map(str,[[i+j for j in range(3)] for i in range(10)]))
data += ['[[]']
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"strings":data}
)
result = df["strings"].apply(func)
```